Google Forms with Google Sheets using GAS
We are using Google forms for an event registration. The form is linked to a Google sheet which uses the following script to achieve certain functions, one of which, is to do an HTTP post when something changes:
function uuid_v2(range) {
  return Array.isArray(range) ? range.map(row => row.map(cell => cell === '' ? '' : Utilities.getUuid())) : (range === '' ? '' : Utilities.getUuid());
}

function sentinelAgent(e){
  Logger.log("Invoking sentinelAgent...");
  FormApp.getActiveForm();
  Logger.log("Event Type: " + e.changeType);
  Logger.log("Event details: " + JSON.stringify(e));

  if(e.changeType=="EDIT" || e.changeType=="INSERT_ROW"){ //The type of change (EDIT, INSERT_ROW, INSERT_COLUMN, REMOVE_ROW, REMOVE_COLUMN, INSERT_GRID, REMOVE_GRID, FORMAT, or OTHER)
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //get activated Spreadsheet
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Overview"); //get sheet by sheet name
    var headings = sheet.getDataRange().offset(0, 0, 1).getValues()[0]; //get heading
    var column_to_watch = 6; //A=1, B=2, C=3 etc...
    
    var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
    var column = sheet.getActiveRange().getColumn();
    
    if (e.changeType=="EDIT" && column != column_to_watch)
      return;
    
    var values = sheet.getSheetValues(
        row, // starting row
        1, // starting column
        1, // number of rows
        7 // number of columns
    );
    
    var payload ={}
    
    for (i = 0; i < headings.length; i++) {
      var name = headings[i];
      var value = values[0][i];
      payload[name] = value;
    }
    payload["row_number"] = row;
    payload["change_type"] = e.changeType;
    
    var payload = {
        'method': 'post',
        'contentType': 'application/json',
        'payload': JSON.stringify(payload)
    };
    var _response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
                  _url,
                  {
                    method: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    payload: JSON.stringify(payload),
                    muteHttpExceptions: true,
                  }
                );
      var responseCode = _response.getResponseCode()
      var responseBody = _response.getContentText()
      Logger.log("Outbound request: " + JSON.stringify(payload));
      if (responseCode > 200 && responseCode < 250) {
        var responseJson = JSON.parse(responseBody)
        Logger.log("Inbound response: " + JSON.stringify(responseJson));
      } else {
        Logger.log(Utilities.formatString("Request failed. Expected 200, got %d: %s", responseCode, responseBody))
      }
  }
}

Here's a screen of header from Google Sheets:

When an existing row is modified, the OnChange trigger (of a custom function) works as expected and the entire record is transferred to an API service. However, the OnChange trigger does not work for a new row insertion. An event with type INSERT_ROW is never evident on logs when the form submission occurs. Any thoughts as to whats wrong with this script?
Setting up a trigger for FormSubmit does transfer the the form data. BUT, they do not contain additional fields calculated within the Google sheet after a new row is inserted, such as, static_id and compute_id.
Here's a screen of the triggers:

references:

https://issuetracker.google.com/u/0/issues/118921815?pli=1
https://medium.com/@eyalgershon/sending-a-webhook-for-new-or-updated-rows-in-google-sheets-e0c9d6a8cb45
https://medium.com/quiqup-engineering/create-webhooks-from-google-sheets-cba629151909
https://blog.harveydelaney.com/setting-up-a-mock-api-for-your-front-end-react-project/
https://medium.com/@eyalgershon/sending-a-webhook-for-each-google-forms-submission-a0e73f72b397


In https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions the term custom function refers a Google Apps Script/JavaScript function to be used in a Google Sheets formula. What do you mean by "custom function"?

7 // number of columns — column H is never read, and values[0][7] will always be undefined.

@Wicket the phrase custom function, in this case, refers to the functions defined within the GAS wizard...

@doubleunary yes, true for "new" records when transferred by a trigger setup directly on Google Forms, as opposed to the linked Google Sheet.

@doubleunary I thank fully acknowledge the feedback. I do understand the reason for undefined as I indicate this "Setting up a trigger for FormSubmit does transfer the the form data. BUT, they do not contain additional fields calculated within the Google sheet after a new row is inserted, such as, static_id and compute_id."
The key question was, if the behavior of google form's insertion of new row in the linked sheet never marking an event of type INSERT_ROW, is expected/intended.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Instead of relying on formulas, do the calculations using the function called by the form submit trigger.

For Google Form submissions that are sent to a spreadsheet, use a spreadsheet on-form submit trigger instead of an on-change trigger.
The event object includes a range property of the target range as well as properties holding the form submission values.
References

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events


I changed the approach and employing your suggestion solves the problem. thanks.
